# Will all Eddystone™ capable beacons support URL transmission?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, eddystone, eddystone-url

I'm new to this beacon technology. I want to use this technology. I did some R&D on this and came to know that Estimote ,RadiusNetworks and some other are we can use. But now I want to take a Beacon which will support most of the concepts like

- Should be capable of both  Eddystone™ & iBeacon™
- Transmit some sensor's (not necessory) data
- Transmit URL

Now my question is 
if the beacon is capable of Eddystone™ then will it transmits URL?

If you have any idea on Beacons for testing all the features & usecases which beacon you'll prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eddystone standards consist of multiple frames including UID, URL, TLM and EID, **there is no requirement that all beacon models implement all these standards** implement all of them.  You should **check with the manufacturer** to verify before purchasing.  The same goes for iBeacon format support.

Generally, any beacon that supports Eddystone at all supports the UID, URL and TLM frames.  The EID frame was added later so older Eddystone beacons certainly do not support it.

For Radius Networks beacons, Eddystone-URL is supported by all Eddystone compatible models, as is iBeacon  and newer models sold since May 2016 support Eddystone-EID as well.

Full disclosure: I work for Radius Networks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @davidgyoung. I need more clarification on Beacons. Which beacon I need to prefer as a part of testing the all usecases of beacons. (on low cost)?

Comment: Recommending a beacon goes beyond what we are supposed to do in this forum, which is supposed to be dedicated to tech Q&A.  I can say that for testing, most beacons are pretty affordable.  My company's RadBeacon Dot is $10 in quantity and supports Eddystone URL and UID (to get Eddystone EID beacons are often codt more).